# Is it possible to use DDPG for discrete action space?

Tags: neural-networks, reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

In Deep Deterministic Policy Gradients(DDPG) method, we use two neural networks, one is Actor and the other is Critic.

From actor-network, we can directly map states to actions (the output of the network directly the output) instead of outputting the probability distribution across a discrete action space. It especially advantages in continuous action space problem so that most examples that I've found using a sigmoid function as the output activation function in Actor-network and multiply by action maximum bound.

However, my model has discrete actions (e.q. integer index [0-125]). In this case, how should I build the output layer of actor-network? should I also use a sigmoid function and just transfer it as an integer by brute-force?

Answer (score 2):

DDPG extends actor-critic methods from the discrete action-space environments they were originally developed on to continous action-space environments.

With that in mind -- sure, you can use actor-critic methods with discrete action-spaces, but it doesn't really make sense to talk about "DDPG" anymore.

> In this case, how should I build the output layer of actor-network?

Typically for a discrete action, $\pi$ is bernoulli with $p$ parameterized by the output of the network.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled for a while with this same question. Actually, like shimao said, DDPG is the continuous action space version of actor-critic method. So for discrete action space, you may use DQN or Double-DQN instead.

Comment: You can only use the answer space for answers even if you don't have enough reputation to comment.

Answer (score 0):

In general, well you could. You can always write a code in your `env.step(a)` function that takes *any* continuous representation of your action and discretisze it. This modification is transparent to DDPG. As far the agent is considered, it just deals with a very peculiar kind of environment.

**The question, is would it be helpful?**

**Answer:** Depending on the representation of the action, it *might help **a lot***. This is particularly useful if your action vector is very large but it factorizes.

As an example, imagine that you need to output an integer in `[1, 2^K]`. A discrete space treatment would require `2^K` outputs which becomes prohibitly expensive even with moderate `K` values. However, you can re-structure your problem so that your DDPG's policy network outputs a `K`-sized vector with each element in (0,1), which is then discretized by the environment to `{0,1}^K` and then converted to the integer value.

Obviously, you could have many more factorizations (or econdings/decondings) of your action.

Answer (score -1):

Actor critic methods wasn't originally developed for discrete action - spaces in fact it's exact opposite.

**DDPG** born from lack of training off policy on continuous action spaces  , since all proper actor critic algorithms are on policy and they have horrendous sample efficiency.

**DDPG** with discrete actions is basically **DQN** with improvements. Newer versions of **DQN** such as **C51** and Rainbow nets are much more refined for your need , if you need discrete actions with off policy training.

Comment: Welcome to the site, @paypaytr. CV is a strict Q&A site, not a discussion forum. Please edit your post to be a stand-alone answer to the question at the top of the thread, & not a discussion of other answers. The "Your Answer" field should only be used to provide answers to the OP's question. Since you're new here, you may
want to take our [tour], which has information for new users.